# C# ASP.Net Core MVC Localization

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, localization

The problem is next:

I have a class library which name is Resources. In there i have .resx files, forexample Lang.es-US.resx and more..

I made a public Lang class in this ClassLib and i try to use it in Index.cshtml, but it is not work. It is only show the default string and not the default key's value.

```
`
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using Resources
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Lang> HtmlLocalizer
@inject IStringLocalizer<Lang> StringLocalizer


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>@HtmlLocalizer["default"].Value</h1>
    <h1>@StringLocalizer["default"].Value</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with     ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
`
```

Here is my config on Program.cs:

```
`
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;

using Resources;

using WebApplication1;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddLocalization();

builder.Services.AddMvc()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            factory.Create(typeof(Lang));
    })
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);


var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRequestLocalization(Helper.GetLocalization(app.Configuration));

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
`
```

Here is Helper.cs

namespace WebApplication1
{
public static class Helper
{
public static RequestLocalizationOptions GetLocalization(IConfiguration configuration)
{
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US" };

```
            var localizationsOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
                .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0]);

            localizationsOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();

            return localizationsOptions;
        }
    }
}
``
```

What i did wrongly?

I try to follow these steps but it is now work for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: `I try to follow these steps but it is now work for me.` So you have solved this issue now?

Comment: Actually the .resx file is good now and it is work with my customstinrglocalizat["Name"].Value, but i don't know how should i use it in data annotations and custom attribute annotations.